# Change file tab colour - PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How do I change the color of the filename as on the picture...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm will automatically change the color of tabs in your projects to give you useful information via color changes (in particular with git integration). Refer to this page for more info: [Pycharm tab colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-status-highlights.html)